# Can no_console_suspend be set in runtime?

Tags: kernel, options, kernel-parameters

Is it possible to change this value in runtime without rebooting? I don't always have this problem, when I suspend right now I'm getting a failure and

> Suspending console(s) (use `no_console_suspend` to debug)

I would like to debug now, without having to reboot and recreate the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes:

```
echo N | sudo tee /sys/module/printk/parameters/console_suspend
```